# Repeater field in Customizer

Tags: theme-customizer

I'd like to develop a setting/control for Customizer that allows **dynamically to add fields**. The typical example would be the possibility to **add an unlimited number of slides** to an slider in a Theme. There would be a button in the Customizer setting called "Add new slide" that allows to add a new slide field.

For the sake of the responses, **let's make it easy: Just a text field per row**. So each time we click on a "Add new row" button, a new text field is generated.

I've tried different approaches and my latest one was an attempt to use script templates (Mustache) like this example: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2015/06/05/javascript-templating-in-the-wordpress-customizer

The problem is how to **handle dynamically those settings**? How to use the WP_Customize_Control **to_json** function and how to get that Mustache template and duplicate it every time we click on the "Add new" button? I have a very good background on PHP and a medium level on JS so I can understand advanced topics.

Answer (score 6):

You could use or take a reference from **[Kirki](http://aristath.github.io/kirki/)**. It is a framework that allow to add customizer controls with less code.

Take a look to Kirki::Repeater_Control [here](https://kirki.org/docs/controls/repeater).

Answer (score 2):

This is awesome,have a look it's the best
https://github.com/cristian-ungureanu/customizer-repeater